# List is a raw type. References to generic type List<E> should be parameterized

Tags: java, generics, types

Below is my syntax

```
List synchronizedpubliesdList = Collections.synchronizedList(publiesdList);
```

I am getting a syntax error of:

`List is a raw type. References to generic type List<E> should be parameterized.`

Please suggest the solution.

Comment: This is a warning, not an error. This line of code will compile but javac will not do all the type checks.

Answer (score 41):

I believe that

> List is a raw type. References to generic type List should be parameterized

is not an error, but a warning.

Understanding generics is a cornerstone if you are planning to use Java so I suggest that you should check out Java's tutorial pages about this:

[java generics tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

So if you know what type of objects are contained in `publiesdList`, than you can do this:

```
List<YourType> synchronizedpubliesdList = Collections.synchronizedList(publiesdList);
```

If there are multiple types of objects in your list than you can use a wildcard:

```
List<?> synchronizedpubliesdList = Collections.synchronizedList(publiesdList);
```

Or if you just want to get rid of the warning than you can suppress it like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
List synchronizedpubliesdList = Collections.synchronizedList(publiesdList);
```

the latter is not recommended however.

Comment: Perfect. I got past this same issue by Adding Generic<> to the declaration and Generic<type>() to the instantiation in my code.
thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You need to give it the correct generic type e.g.

```
List<String> publiesdList = ...
List<String> synchronizedpubliesdList = Collections.synchronizedList(publiesdList);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may define "publiesdList" this way:

```
List<String> publiesdList = new List<String>();
```

The warning will dissappear.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same warnings in Eclipse and just click on the warning sign and get the option of adding a type argument to the Hash, List, Array or what have you.
Big list of discussion here [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)